# PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605:

Tags: magento-1.9, error, paypal, payment-methods

[image][image]This error occurred when the customer has clicked the PayPal button:

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).

Could you help me what should i do?

[image]

Comment: @Yordan: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 6):

Paypal does not support all currencies.
You can find a list of supported currencies in `Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::$_supportedCurrencyCodes`.

> 'AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
>           'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB'

You can make your base currency one of the supported currencies, enter your prices in the supported currency, fill in a conversion rate and use on frontend only your currency. Not a pretty solution but it should work.

Comment: Thank you i just change only USD and its work!!! How about if i want to use my country currency it is IDR

Comment: @RenalYordan. I explained In the answer. Make USD the default currency (this means that all your prices have to be entered in USD) then add IDR as a second currency. Allow inly IDR to be used in the website (you can do this from the system->configuration->currency section). Fill in an exchange rate (System->Currency).

Comment: How can i allow my default currency on the screen? Showing ---> IDR is it possible?

Comment: System->Configuration->Currency Setup. Set Base currency to USD and in allowed currencies select only IDR

Comment: is it correct like this?  Base currency USD  display currency: IDR Allow currency: IDR, after i am setup like this the screen of the product still show USD

Comment: You need to fill in an exchange rate from System->Currency Rates

Comment: Iam confused pleasee see my screen shot, do you have skype? Thank you!!!

Comment: @Marius Is there any method that does not require to change base currency?

Comment: I don't know any

Comment: @Marius : As you told, System->Configuration->Currency Setup. Set Base currency to USD and in allowed currencies select only IDR,, if I set like this, my price changed to the dollar, I need, my country price needs to display and also PayPal work. is any possible? and  I have posted my question,, :: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45295908/7652787

Comment: @Marius Customers are try to place an order using US dollar, still they are facing same error, what is the cause of this error? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used small trick to rid this error. It is not good solution but sometime it is useful.

Go to app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout.php. Find the public function start and find below code

```
$this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal())
            ->setCurrencyCode($this->_quote->getBaseCurrencyCode())
            ->setInvNum($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId())
            ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
            ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
            ->setSolutionType($solutionType)
            ->setPaymentAction($this->_config->paymentAction);

Just replace the below code  

$this->_api->setAmount($this->_quote->getBaseGrandTotal())
            ->setCurrencyCode('USD')
            ->setInvNum($this->_quote->getReservedOrderId())
            ->setReturnUrl($returnUrl)
            ->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl)
            ->setSolutionType($solutionType)
            ->setPaymentAction($this->_config->paymentAction);
```

With this trick now you will go to paypal without any error. But you have to convert the price from Base Currency to USD.

Note: This solution is only for Paypal Express Users.

Code Taken From: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/11/paypal-gateway-has-rejected-request.html

Comment: @rana : after applied your code, all the price display like a dollar at payment page.